# Will collection data from Flow in viewModelScope maybe block UI in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The Code A is from official [article](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow) about Flow

`viewModelScope.launch{}` run in UI thread by default, I think `suspend fun fetchLatestNews()` will run in UI thread by default too, so I think Code A maybe cause UI blocked when `fetchLatestNews()` is long time operation, right?

I think Code B can fix the problem, right?

**Code A**

```
class LatestNewsViewModel(
    private val newsRepository: NewsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // Trigger the flow and consume its elements using collect
            newsRepository.favoriteLatestNews.collect { favoriteNews ->
                // Update View with the latest favorite news
            }
        }
    }
}



class NewsRemoteDataSource(
    private val newsApi: NewsApi,
    private val refreshIntervalMs: Long = 5000
) {
    val latestNews: Flow<List<ArticleHeadline>> = flow {
        while(true) {
            val latestNews = newsApi.fetchLatestNews()
            emit(latestNews) // Emits the result of the request to the flow
            delay(refreshIntervalMs) // Suspends the coroutine for some time
        }
    }
}

// Interface that provides a way to make network requests with suspend functions
interface NewsApi {
    suspend fun fetchLatestNews(): List<ArticleHeadline>
}
```

**Code B**

```
class LatestNewsViewModel(
    private val newsRepository: NewsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
           //The same
        }
    }
}


//The same
```

**Added content:**

To Tenfour04: Thanks!

I think a suspend function maybe block UI, so I think to define `dispatchers` is the most important in order not to block UI! Is it right?

Code 1 work well when I click "Start" button to display the information if I use `Dispatchers.IO`.

Code 2 is freezed and no information updated when I click "Start" button if I use `Dispatchers.Main`.

Code 3 can work just like Code 1 if I use `Dispatchers.Main`, the reason is only because I set `delay(100)`.

BTW, Flow is suspend. So if there is a long time operation even if it's wrapped with coroutine instead of `soundDbFlow().collect { myInfo.value = it.toString() }`, I think I can get the same test result just like Code 1, Code 2 and Code 3.

And more, Code 4 is OK after I added `flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)` for the Flow even if it is launched in `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){}` !

**Code 1 OK**

```
class HandleMeter: ViewModel() {
    var myInfo = mutableStateOf("World")
    private var myJob: Job?=null
    private var k=0

    private fun soundDbFlow() = flow {
          while (true) {
             emit(k++)
             delay(0)
          }
   }

    fun calCurrentAsynNew() {
        myJob?.cancel()
        myJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            soundDbFlow().collect { myInfo.value = it.toString() }
        }
    }

    fun cancelJob(){
        myJob?.cancel()
    }

}


@Composable
fun Greeting(handleMeter: HandleMeter) {
    var info = handleMeter.myInfo
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello ${info.value}")

        Button(
            onClick = { handleMeter.calCurrentAsynNew() }
        ) {
            Text("Start")
        }

        Button(
            onClick = { handleMeter.cancelJob() }
        ) {
            Text("Stop")
        }
    }
}
```

**Code 2 Freezed**

```
class HandleMeter: ViewModel() {
   private fun soundDbFlow() = flow {
          while (true) {
             emit(k++)
             delay(0)
          }
   }

    fun calCurrentAsynNew() {
        myJob?.cancel()
        myJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
            soundDbFlow().collect { myInfo.value = it.toString() }
        }
    }
    ...
   //The same

}
...
//The same
```

**Code 3 OK**

```
class HandleMeter: ViewModel() {
   private fun soundDbFlow() = flow {
          while (true) {
             emit(k++)
             delay(100)  //It's 100
          }
   }

    fun calCurrentAsynNew() {
        myJob?.cancel()
        myJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
            soundDbFlow().collect { myInfo.value = it.toString() }
        }
    }
    ...
    //The same

}
...
//The same
```

**Code 4 Ok**

```
class HandleMeter: ViewModel() {
   private fun soundDbFlow() = flow {
        while (true) {
            emit(k++)
            delay(0)
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)// I added

    fun calCurrentAsynNew() {
        myJob?.cancel()
        myJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
            soundDbFlow().collect { myInfo.value = it.toString() }
        }
    }

    ...
    //The same

}
...
//The same
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A suspend function does not block unless it breaks the convention that a suspend function must never block. Therefore, it doesn't matter that your coroutine is called from the Main dispatcher. The main thread will not be blocked by calling `fetchLatestNews()`, *unless* you have improperly composed the implementation of the function such that it actually blocks.

You usually do not need to do this like in your **Code B**:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
```

because you usually aren't calling blocking functions at the top level of your coroutine. If you are, you can wrap those pieces in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { }`. It's generally more convenient to leave the coroutine on the Main dispatcher, since there are so many non-suspend functions in Android that require that you call them from the main thread. If you flip it around you're likely to need `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { }` in more places than you would have needed the inverse, and you also incur a one frame delay before the coroutine actually starts. Also, if your coroutines interact with properties in your ViewModel, you avoid potential problems with concurrent access to the properties if you only touch them from the Main dispatcher, since it is single-threaded.

There might be exceptions where you're launching a coroutine that doesn't interact with any such Main-required functions and that directly calls blocking functions, but I think that should be rare, especially if you practice good encapsulation ([see here](https://www.techyourchance.com/single-level-of-abstraction-principle/)). If you break a chunk of code out of the top level of your coroutine into its own function, you can make that separate function into a suspend function that uses `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` if necessary. Then your top level coroutine will look very clean.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the `viewModelScope.launch { }` will not block main thread, but the body of the `viewModelScope.launch { }` is `suspend fun fetchLatestNews()` which will run in main thread.  If `suspend fun fetchLatestNews()` is long time operation, I think it will cause main thread stutter.

So I think I should use Code B, or use `suspend fun fetchLatestNews():List<ArticleHeadline> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){... }` in Code A , right?

Comment: No, because `fetchLatestNews()` is a suspend function, it will not block the thread/dispatcher it is called from as long as it is written correctly and uses `withContext` *internally* to wrap any blocking code. This is the whole point of `suspend` functions: **they do not block**. A proper suspend function is safe to call at any time from anywhere without using `withContext`, and it will not cause stuttering or freezing.

Comment: Thanks!  But I don't think `This is the whole point of suspend functions: they do not block.' is always correct. If a long time operation suspend function run in main thread, maybe it will cause main thread stutter.

Comment: A long time suspend function doesn’t run on the main thread, even if it’s called from the main dispatcher because a suspend function delegates to an appropriate dispatcher internally. If you still don’t believe me, write a coroutine `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { delay(30_000); println(“done”) }` and call it. There will be no stutter even though it takes 30 seconds to call the suspend function `delay()`.

Comment: It is possible to write a bad suspend function like `suspend fun foo() { Thread.sleep(1000L) }` and if you do and call it from the main dispatcher, it will freeze the UI, but if you do this, you are breaking the rules of writing a suspend function and there will be a compiler warning. It’s like overriding `equals()` without overriding `hashcode()`. It’s possible to do it, but you are breaking the rules and things won’t work properly if you do.

Comment: This article by the lead designer of Kotlin coroutines explains this concept in detail. https://elizarov.medium.com/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761

Comment: Thanks! But by you said `a suspend function delegates to an appropriate dispatcher internall` , nobody need  to write the code such as `suspend fun soundDb(): Double = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {..} ` .

Comment: I think maybe we have a language barrier. By internally I mean just what you wrote. Whoever composes the function `soundDb()` is expected to make sure it doesn’t block if they marked it `suspend` and it will look like your comment. If they failed to do that, they have done it wrong. The person who writes the coroutine that calls `soundDb()` does not wrap it in withContext because they trust that whoever wrote `soundDb()` did it correctly. You should never have to wrap a call to a suspend function in withContext.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: You've come up with an interesting example. In Code 2, you have created a Flow that has a `while (true)` loop. `delay(0)` does nothing, so this Flow will behave just like a blocking `while(true)` loop when you call `collect` on it, so you could avoid blocking Main by collecting from Dispatchers.Default, although this still isn't good because it will block one of the CPU cores indefinitely. At least it won't block main. To fix this Flow so it can work on Dispatchers.Main, replace `delay(0)` with `delay(1)` or `yield()`. This is because `delay(0)` is optimized not to suspend if the duration is 0

Comment: Thanks! Code 4 I just added in my question is OK after I added `flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)` for the Flow even if it is launched in `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){}` !

Comment: That makes sense. `flowOn` determines the dispatcher that `collect` will internally run on. Did you have a question about it? What more are you looking for in an answer? The article I linked in my comment above has the same information I've been talking about, and it's by the lead designer of Kotlin coroutines. I don't know what's more reputable than that.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think a suspend function maybe block UI, so I think to define dispatchers is the most important in order not to block UI! Is it right?

Comment: No, that is not right. I’ve said it over and over, that is not right. If you have a suspend function that blocks the UI, it’s the suspend function that has something wrong with it, not your coroutine that is calling it. Specifying a dispatcher in the coroutine is a “band-aid” that might prevent blocking the main thread but doesn’t fix the root problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Code A will not block the UI thread, because the `launch` method does not block the current thread.

As the documentation says:

> Launches a new coroutine without blocking the current thread and returns a reference to the coroutine as a [Job].

> If the context does not have any dispatcher nor any other [ContinuationInterceptor], then [Dispatchers.Default] is used.

So in your case, CodeA uses the `Dispatches.Default` under the hood, while CodeB uses the `Dispatchers.IO`

More on coroutines [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)

Comment: Code A doesn't block the UI thread, but not for the reason you gave. It doesn't block because the example doesn't have any blocking functions in it. Code A doesn't use `Dispatchers.Default`. It uses `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` because that's in the  CoroutineContext that `viewModelScope` is declared with. It starts synchronously up to its first suspension point and any blocking functions in it that aren't delegated to other dispatchers *will* block the Main thread.

Answer (score 0):

@qki wrote right. But his answer has inaccuracy. ViewModel have viewModelScope. viewModelScope have context SuperVisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main.immediatly. LatestNewsViewModel's init will be execute in main group threads, but this will not block ui thread.

Comment: Thanks! The body of `viewModelScope.launch {...}` run in main thread, if the body is long time operation, I think it will cause App ANR,right?

Comment: @HelloCW Yes, an ANR or at least stuttering, and that's why you should never do blocking work in a coroutine without wrapping it in `withContext`.

Comment: No. This don't throw ANR. Because Main is pull threads of main group. This isn't block main thread. Main dispatcher work with pull other threads, which is defined in main group (read ThreadGroup).